# Mudar valor do php com váriavel na url?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$ip = 'stream.radioturn.com.br';
$port   = '8000';
```

Gostaria de mudar os mesmos valores com uma váriavel na url, por ex:

```
app.php?ip=ipqualquer.com.br&port=2531
```

E assim exibiria o mesmo código porém com os valores da nova url

como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce pode usar o metodo GET :

```
$ip=$_GET['ip'];
$port=$_GET['port'];
```

Se você fizer dessa forma, e não passar as variaveis, provavelmente terá um erro exibido. Então faça dessa forma:

```
//verificando a existencia
if(isset($_GET['ip']) && isset($_GET['port'])){
// se existir
$ip=$_GET['ip'];
$port=$_GET['port'];
} else{
// aqui não existe, ai voce pode passar outros valores
$ip='ip padrao';
$port='porta padrao';

}
```

Ou com o if e else simplificado que tem o mesmo efeito:

```
$ip=isset($_GET['ip'])?$_GET['ip']:'ip padrao';
$port=isset($_GET['port'])?$_GET['port']:'Porta padrao';
```

Comment: vou tentar isso

Comment: Não funcionou, aconteceu isso: http://radioturn.com.br/live/app.php?ip=stream.radioturn.com.br&port=8000

Comment: Eu errei no metodo, corrigi ali

Comment: Consegui, obrigado!

Comment: é possível definir um valor padrão? pra caso eu entre apenas em app.php? sem a variavel

Comment: Vou citar um exemplo, pera ai

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho, dá uma olhada :)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Só um ponto para acrescentar, caso seja PHP 7, pode usar o operador ternário assim: `$ip = $_GET['ip'] ?? 'ip padrao';`